# OpenCV errors reported in CLion

Tags: opencv, syntax-error, clion

I am working on integrating OpenCV (using the source files from the GitHub repo) in an application using CLion as my IDE. I am using Ubuntu but others working in the repository are using Windows. All of the OpenCV C++ header files are riddled with error messages, which both CLion and Visual Studio claim to be syntax errors. The errors do not appear if a header file is opened by itself in Visual Studio, however.

For example, the following sequence of code from the core.hpp file results in about seven errors.

```
class CV_EXPORTS Exception : public std::exception
{
public:
```

CLion indicates that a type is expected before each "public" statement, a declarator is expected after "std::exception", a semi-colon is expected after the first colon, among other errors.

Does anyone have any insights as to what could be causing these errors? The OpenCV directory is included in the repository, but maybe it isn't properly included in the project in some other way?

I do not want to fully build OpenCV on my Linux system because others are working in Windows, so I would like to be able to just use the source files alone.

Comment: It's a long shot, but have you included the proper headers to access `std::exception`?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's an include problem. Can you please post the directory where you are keeping opencv headers, `export | grep PATH` output, `export | grep CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` output, and your CMakeList file for the CLion project.